# ipywidgets compatible with Jupyter Lab version 1.0+?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I want to use the pre-release Jupyter Lab version 1.0+. I have a `Pipfile` that looks like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
ipywidgets = "*"
jupyterlab = ">=1.0.0a0"
...

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

which installs the following versions:

- `jupyterlab==1.0.0rc0`
- `ipywidgets==7.4.2`
- `notebook==5.7.8`
- `widgetsnbextension==3.4.2`

I then run the command `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`. It installs the labextension:

- `@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.39.1`.

I can't get the widgets to appear in the notebook.

[image]

I know it can cause problems to have mismatched Jupyter Lab & Jupyter Widgets versions. Is there a version of Jupyter Widgets compatible with version 1.0 of Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly old but I came across this as I had a similar problem myself using AWS `SageMaker` which is currently still pinned to version 1 of `jupyter lab`.

I was able to recreate your problem more or less and I think there's two separate issues here:

1. Your requirements have conflicting `tornado` dependencies. I wasn't even able to execute any cells and would instead get an error in the console like `AttributeError: 'WebSocketProtocol13' object has no attribute 'is_closing'`. Running `pip-compile` from `pip-tools` on the requirements revealed the incompatible `tornado` versions. This can be fixed by changing your version of `jupyter lab`, I figure there must have been an issue with that version being the first patch of a major version. Since you have a requirement for it to be 1.0.*, upgrading to 1.0.10 fixed the issue for me.
2. However the second issue is your version of `jupyterlab-manager` rather than `ipywidgets`. Compatible versions corresponding to different versions of `jupyter lab` are listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager). In your case, you must install v1.0. I'm not sure why v0.39.1 is being installed but you can set this like `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0`.

Doing both of those allows `ipywidgets` widgets to render properly.